# asp.net mvc async await making main thread not blocking

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, task-parallel-library

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Search(string q)
  {    
       var data = db.MediaPlanBilingInvoices.Where(m => m.IsDeleted == false);
            //allthe stuff        


            decimal? allinvoicetotal=0;
            decimal? allrototal = 0;
            if (Noofrecords > 0)
            {                
                    if (WebConstants.PrintMedia)
                    {
                       var roobject = data.Where(x => x.isPrint == true).SelectMany(m => m.MediaPlanBilingInvoiceDetails);
                       var roobjects =roobject.Select(m=>m.RoId);

                       Func<decimal?> functions = new Func<decimal?>(() => roobject.Sum(m => m.MediaPlanRO.MediaPlanROPrints.Sum(qq => qq.MediaPlanPrint.Amount)));
                       var tasksro = await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew<decimal?>(functions);    


                       allrototal = allrototal + tasksro.Result;

                }
                else if (WebConstants.ElectronicMedia)
                {
                    var roobject = data.Where(x => x.iselectronic == true).SelectMany(m => m.MediaPlanBilingInvoiceDetails);
                    var roobjects =roobject.Select(m=>m.RoId);

                    Func<decimal?> functions = new Func<decimal?>(() => roobject.Sum(m => m.MediaPlanRO.MediaPlanROPrints.Sum(qq => qq.MediaPlanPrint.Amount)));
                    var tasksro = await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew<decimal?>functions);   


                   allrototal = allrototal + tasksro ;
                }
              }                   
          }

                return Viewdata);
            }
        }
```

I am trying to calculate the sum of the ros in the different table for different criteria.

The problem is that when the program reachers **allrototal** it stops and doesn't go to the next line until it bring down the result. I want to keep it running not stop there. how can i do it?

Comment: Thats what async/await do. It makes thread non-blocking so that other request can use it.

Comment: This is how async/await works, until the result is available you can't use it.

Comment: As soon as the pgogram find startnew it will start executing the query in the background?

Comment: So i guess i have to get the result at the end of the program?

Comment: Shout out to a media buying bro!

Comment: basically i am trying to decrease the time of page load

Comment: @maz3tt One important thing to bear in mind: async does not necessarily reduce load times (especially if parallel tasks are not possible) but it optimises use of threads (i.e. it allows threads to used for other things during long-running operations).

Comment: Did you read the [StartNew is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) article?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core problem you're having is that [`async` doesn't change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html) (discussed in detail on my blog). With HTTP, you have one request and one response. If you return a response, then you can't *also* have something else running and then return *another* response later - HTTP just doesn't work that way.

So, on ASP.NET, `async` allows you to free up the *thread* but does *not* complete the response. The response is not sent until the `async` method is finished.

Furthermore, [`Task.Run` is safer than `StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), but *neither* of them should be used like this on ASP.NET because all it's doing is freeing up the request thread pool thread by using up another thread pool thread. So `await Task.Run(() => functions());` is just a more expensive way of saying `functions()`.

This method should just be made synchronous. There's no asynchronous work to do here. If you want your client to behave asynchronously, then your *client* will need to make its HTTP request asynchronously.

Comment: You have tons of articles regarding asynchronous. so what's your opinion if i break the above 50 sec query into 5 10 secs query. to many threads?

Comment: 10 sec query running in parallel

Comment: @maz3tt: It's dangerous, IMO. You can certainly *try*, but you will need to test under realistic load conditions. Parallelism on ASP.NET usually doesn't work out very well in production, unless you *know* your number of requests will always be low. Each request hitting this will take up 5 threads instead of 1, and a thread is one of the heaviest resources in a request, so your server's scalability would be considerably limited.

Comment: Ok i can see now where it is taking, so i will not try that, thanks